# Filter the rows of the last N group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have created the following query (I use SQL Server), which returns the following output:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID
```

[image]

In such case how can I update my above query to select only the 2 last CLIENT ID, and I should be able to use whatever other number like last 20, last 60, last 100, etc

In my example the expected output would be

[image]

meaning that we see only the rows related to the 2 last clients which are client B99 and C93 (meaning that first client A19 is filtered out since it does not belong to the last 2)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Use [`dense_rank()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: "last" by what? Ambiguous (could be alpha on first column, numeric by second column, by sum of second column, by avg of second column...

Comment: @AaronBertrand  last according to the client_id column output of my first query

Comment: It is still unclear what last means. /shrug

Comment: @AaronBertrand if OP is ordering by `client_id` then doesn't last mean that rows that are returned at the bottom of the resultset? :)

Comment: If that's a requirement (a particular ordering) that should have been mentioned by the OP. We're only guessing intent based on the data sample.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the question *does* provide a particular order, the query has an order by. Not sure why everyone is saying its missing an order.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the expected output. But as others already mentioned it's unclear what `last` mean. I'm just guessing from your expected result.
Also please don't post photo of tables next time.

```
SELECT A.CLIENT_ID, A.PRICE_BILL
FROM DB A
WHERE A.CLIENT_ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP(2) A.CLIENT_ID
    FROM DB A
    ORDER BY A.CLIENT_ID DESC
)
ORDER BY A.CLIENT_ID ASC, A.PRICE_BILL ASC
```

[See Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kbFDi47T)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you require using [`dense_rank()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and filtering out the last 2 rankings.

The reason you use `dense_rank` is because it assigns the same ranking to ties thereby ranking all of the same `CLIENT_ID` the same. Also note the reverse ordering of the `dense_rank` to make it easy to filter out the last 2 values because they are ranked 1 & 2.

```
declare @MyTable table (CLIENT_ID varchar(3), PRICE_BILL int);

insert into @MyTable (CLIENT_ID, PRICE_BILL)
values
('A19',91), ('A19',29), ('A19',92)
, ('B99',85), ('B99',202)
, ('C93',399), ('C93',929), ('C93',929);

with cte as (
    select *
        , dense_rank() over (order by CLIENT_ID desc) dr
    from @MyTable
)
select *
from cte
where dr < 3
order by CLIENT_ID;
```

Returns:

| CLIENT_ID | PRICE_BILL | dr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B99 | 85 | 2 |
| B99 | 202 | 2 |
| C93 | 399 | 1 |
| C93 | 929 | 1 |
| C93 | 929 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S3keJrLP)

Note the provision of sample data as DDL+DML makes it much easier for people to assist.